# WordPress + Vue — Single page app giving me 404s when I use query params

Tags: rest-api

I've got my rest api powered site working really well with Vue. Except for the issue of WordPress and urls.

Site: http://mytely.ca/

Search for a name or click on a name and the url updates. Now refresh the page. Everything still works, in that Vue will take over and do all the requests and set things up. But I'm getting a 404 on every page like that.

I don't really know anything about this whole thing. I tried setting up a redirect plugin but that does what it says — it redirects from http://mytely.ca/&page=1&search=John%20Doe  back to http://mytely.ca, which isn't what I want.

I basically want WordPress to ignore the urls completely — just have index.php (and hence Vue) takeover everything. Basically, not 404 and just pass on through with the url.

I'm not currently using Vue Router at all in my app — just appending query strings and using popstate. I'm wondering if I actually need to be using Vue Router to handle this.

Comment: It's not clear what the setup is, but why not have the WP install elsewhere from the Vue frontend, e.g. as a subdomain? (WP also has it's own public query variables that you shouldn't use, when mixing it together)

Comment: True, I could do that. Though I've been trying to keep things on the same domain for simplicity. Everything is going great except for this 404 issue. Can't figure out a way around it.

Comment: or keep WP in a subdirectory or try prefixing your Vue GET parameters?